# Make stored procedures generic

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have to make my stored procedures written in SQL to be generic, so that they can be used in different versions of SQL (also MySQL if possible). I think it can be done if the scripts are written according to ANSI standards. But I have to convert large procedures. There is no tool for direct conversion. Is there any set of rules which can be followed to perform this conversion?

I have found a tool to validate scripts @ http://developer.mimer.com

But this will be very time consuming as I have large SP's and I think by using some rule book, this task can be done in a shorter time.

Comment: There is no such thing as a SQL stored procedure. SQL is a language that is implemented (slightly differently) by many RDBMS'. However, each RDBMS has it's own procedural variant, T-SQL for SQL Server, PL/SQL for Oracle etc. There is no ANSI standard for procedural code so you're completely out of luck. Anything that converts them automatically will almost certainly be fairly crap as each RDBMS is implemented completely differently. Where you would use temporary tables in T-SQL they should normally be completely avoided in PL/SQL.

Comment: The least time consuming (and most efficient) thing to do would be to convert them yourself or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: You will not be able to write generic SQL stored procedures.  Stored procedures require control structures (IF, WHILE) which are not part of standard SQL and also mechanisms to access the pre- and post-insert, update, delete versions of the records and those are also not standard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic stored procedure language.

If you need something to work across database platforms, you would be better to implement the SP functionality in code, using ANSI standard SQL for the database access.